# Is there an example of a 2 functions $h(x)$ and $ɥ(x)$ where $h_c(x)$ and $ɥ_c(x)$ is equal to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity

The function $h(x)$ is continuous everywhere and differentiable everywhere. $h(x)$ must equal to $0$ at least once but not infinitely many times.

The function $ɥ(x)$ is continuous everywhere but $ɥ(x)$ differentiable everywhere besides when $h(x)=0$.

to find $h_1(x)$ and $ɥ_1(x)$ you say $h(x)=h_0(x)$ and $ɥ(x)=ɥ_0(x)$ and follow this rule

$$h_c(x)=h_{c-1}(ɥ_{c-1}(x))+h_{c-1}(x)$$
$$ɥ_c(x)=ɥ_{c-1}((h_{c-1}(x))-ɥ_{c-1}(x)$$
$$so$$
$$h_1(x)=h(ɥ(x))+h(x)$$
$$ɥ_1(x)=ɥ(h(x))-ɥ(x)$$
My question is is there a $h(x)$ and a $ɥ(x)$ where there is a c so this is true $h_c(x)=ɥ_c(x)=0$ and if so what is $h(x)$ and $ɥ(x)$

Comment: I’m a little bit confused with the notation... what does $h_{c}$ represent?

Comment: $h_c(x)$ is doing something to $h(x)$ c times @AirMike

Comment: $h_1(x)=h(ɥ(x))+h(x)$ and $ɥ_1(x)=h(ɥ(x))-ɥ(x)$ and $h_2(x)=h_1(ɥ_1(x))+h_1(x)$ and $ɥ_2(x)=ɥ_1(h_1(x))-ɥ_1(x)$ and so $h_c(x)=h_{c-1}(ɥ_{c-1}(x))+h_{c-1}(x)$ and $ɥ_c=ɥ_{c-1}(h_{c-1}(x))-ɥ_{c-1}(x)$ @AirMike

Comment: @AirMike i understand fixed it